# How to logging IP address with firewalld SNAT?

Tags: centos, logs, nat, firewalld

I try to setting up SNAT with firewalld on my CentOS 8 PC to make NAT router like below.

Users access to the Web Server via CentOS8.

```
[UserPC]---(192.168.0.0/24)---[CentOS 8]---(10.0.0.0/24)---[Web Server]
```

I want to logging 4 IP addresses at a line, like a firewall appliance.

1. UserPC
2. Web Server
3. UserPC (After NAT)
4. Web Server (After NAT,but I don't use DNAT in this case.)

I found the 1.UserPC and 2.WebServer in the /var/log/firewall file.
But I can't logging "3.UserPC(After NAT)" and "4.Web Server(After NAT)".

My CentOS8 PC has 2 NICs.

- Internal I/F : 192.168.0.1/24
- External I/F : 10.0.0.1/24 , 10.0.0.2/24 , 10.0.0.3/24 (3 IPaddresses)

Here are my firewall-cmd rules.

```
ipv4 filter FORWARD 0 -i <Internal I/F> -o <External I/F> -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter FORWARD 0 -m tcp -p tcp -j LOG --log-prefix 'FORWARD LOG:'
ipv4 filter FORWARD 0 -i <External I/F> -o <Internal I/F> -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
ipv4 nat PREROUTING 0 -m tcp -p tcp -j LOG --log-prefix 'PREROUTING LOG:'
ipv4 nat POSTROUTING 0 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -o <External I/F> -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.3
ipv4 nat POSTROUTING 0 -m tcp -p tcp -j LOG --log-prefix 'POSTROUTING LOG:'
ipv4 nat OUTPUT 0 -m tcp -p tcp -j LOG --log-prefix 'OUTPUT LOG:'
```

I checked the access.log in the WebServer, source IP address is "10.0.0.3".
I wonder the order of firewalld rules is not good, I changed the rules order.
But it does not work well.

Next I checked nft list ruleset, I found the rules below.

```
table ip nat {
    chain PREROUTING{
        blahblahblah
    }
    chain INPUT{
        blahblahblah
    }
    chain POSTROUTING{
        type nat hoook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
        oifname "External I/F" ip saddr 192.168.0.0/24 counter packets 2 bytes 120 snat to 10.0.0.1
        meta l4proto tcp counter packets 100 bytes 0 log prefix "POSTROUTING LOG:"
    }
}
```

I think I need to add some statements or keyword or something.
How and what do I have to add to this meta line?
And is my thought correct ?

I would be grateful if anyone could tell me.
Thank you.

Comment: In case it could interest you, here's a completely different method with limitations (eg: you can't use netmasks everywhere, only in (orig) source and (orig) destination) but very simple: `conntrack -E -s 192.168.0.0/24 -d ip.of.web.server  --src-nat`. The `conntrackd` daemon can be configured to log the same kind of result given by the conntrack command. If a firewall doing NAT allowed a flow, this flow *will* have a conntrack entry.

Comment: Thank you A.B . I will try conntrackd and report it.